# What's the effect of space launches on climate?

Tags: climate-change, atmosphere

Do space launches warm or cool the surface temperature (admittedly, for a little bit)? [This](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20220713-how-to-make-rocket-launches-less-polluting) BBC article presents it as an emerging climate problem but also says

> If the amount of black carbon expelled into the atmosphere reach 30 gigagrams a year, or even 100, then there will be some **cooling** of the surface of the planet under this black carbon umbrella.

So what's the whole debate all about then? Isn't it a good thing that it counteracts the warming effect to some degree?

Comment: Solid carbon in the atmosphere is absorving radiation, so it is reducing the amount of radiation reaching to the ground and, reducing (always in a negligible amount) greenhouse effect, that it is produced by some other substances (as cardon dioxide, methane...). Space launches emits different substances depending on the rocket propellant used: liquid gives as result water, and solids, depends on, usually, small amount of metallic elements plus carbon dioxide or monoxide. I didn´t see that link, but it seems that they are mixing  concepts.[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_propellant)